# Are solutions always the same?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we are given some differential equation with variable $x$ and function $y=y(x)$ and solution of this equation is given by $f(x,y) = 0$, where $f$ is some function of two variables. The question is: under what conditions $f(x,y)$ is independent of switching $x$ and $y(x)$ (i.e. in this situation we consider $x$ as a function of $y$).

For example equation $(1+y^2)dx + (xy-y^3)dy = 0$ can be solved using this method, however I am not sure if it always works...